# Converting latitude/longitude to full range referential

Tags: leaflet, latitude-longitude, ios, web-mercator

I have a list of latitudes and longitudes expressed as follow:

```
-1 <= latitude <= 0
0 <= longitude <= 1
```

Those coordinates represent POIs on a fantasy map displayed using the Leaflet JavaScript library using the coordinate system *EPSG:3857* (Web Mercator)

**I need to map those coordinates to the full range of possible latitudes/longitudes** (-90/+90 and -180/+180) in order to display them properly using the iOS MapKit framework.

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio) should help you to convert your range to another one

Comment: @Mazu_R If I was working in a 2D cartesian referential, that answer would apply.
It seems to visually work for the longitude, but not for the latitude.

Comment: Web Mercator distorts data and can't display high latitude values, so your goal is self-defeating. Scaling a make-believe 1x2 map to a 2x1 footprint will deform even Plate Carrée.